# How to restart process if it crashes using powershell?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to run Core Keeper Dedicated Server, everything seems fine, but from time to time CoreKeeperServer.exe crashes. So main Powershell script what launches it not tracking is it crashed or not. How do i need to modify this script, so it constantly (every 1-5 seconds or so) monitored if process still running or not, and start it again if it is? Also i want to keep "press q to exit" functionality what already included in stock script.

Stock script:

```
# Feel free to change these (see README), but keep in mind that changes to this file might be overwritten on update
$CoreKeeperArguments = @("-batchmode", "-logfile", "CoreKeeperServerLog.txt") + $args

$script:ckpid = $null

function Quit-CoreKeeperServer {
    if ($script:ckpid -ne $null) {
        taskkill /pid $ckpid.Id
        Wait-Process -InputObject $ckpid
        Write-Host "Stopped CoreKeeperServer.exe"
    }
}

try {
    if (Test-Path -Path "GameID.txt") {
        Remove-Item -Path "GameID.txt"
    }

    $script:ckpid = Start-Process -PassThru -FilePath %0\..\CoreKeeperServer.exe -ArgumentList $CoreKeeperArguments
    Write-Host "Started CoreKeeperServer.exe"

    # Wait for GameID
    while (!(Test-Path -Path "GameID.txt")) {
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
    }

    Write-Host -NoNewline "Game ID: "
    Get-Content "GameID.txt"
 
    Write-Host "Press q to quit, DON'T close the window or the server process will just keep running"
    While ($KeyInfo.VirtualKeyCode -eq $Null -or $KeyInfo.VirtualKeyCode -ne 81) {
        $KeyInfo = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho, IncludeKeyDown")
    }
}
finally {
    Quit-CoreKeeperServer
    pause
}
```

Comment: How do you know when the server has crashed? Does it write an error to log/console or is there an API that (won't) answer on crash?

Comment: @vonPryz
1. All players was disconnected
2. pid of process do not exists any more.
3. on q key pressed script errors out "pid does not exist(in short)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved problem like this:

```
# Feel free to change these (see README), but keep in mind that changes to this file might be overwritten on update
$CoreKeeperArguments = @("-batchmode", "-logfile", "CoreKeeperServerLog.txt") + $args

$script:ckpid = $null

function Quit-CoreKeeperServer {
    if ($script:ckpid -ne $null) {
        taskkill /pid $ckpid.Id
        Wait-Process -InputObject $ckpid
        Write-Host "Stopped CoreKeeperServer.exe"
    }
}

try {
    if (Test-Path -Path "GameID.txt") {
        Remove-Item -Path "GameID.txt"
    }

    $script:ckpid = Start-Process -PassThru -FilePath %0\..\CoreKeeperServer.exe -ArgumentList $CoreKeeperArguments
    Write-Host "Started CoreKeeperServer.exe"

    # Wait for GameID
    while (!(Test-Path -Path "GameID.txt")) {
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
    }

    Write-Host -NoNewline "Game ID: "
    Get-Content "GameID.txt"
 
    Write-Host "Server is runnig. Press CTRL + C to stop."
    While ($true) {
        if (-not (Get-Process -Id $ckpid.Id -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
        Write-Host “Server is died restarting...”
        Get-Date
        $script:ckpid = Start-Process -PassThru -FilePath %0\..\CoreKeeperServer.exe -ArgumentList $CoreKeeperArguments
        Write-Host "Started CoreKeeperServer.exe"
        Write-Host -NoNewline "Game ID: "
        Get-Content "GameID.txt"
        Write-Host "Server is runnig. Press CTRL + C to stop."
        sleep 1
        }
    }
}
finally {
    Quit-CoreKeeperServer
    pause
}
```

Comment: Answering ones own questions totally all-right imo, but perhaps not just code dump, i mean sharing is caring so good on You for that, but give a few lines in the beginning to explain what the problem was, instead of just giving a solution with a lot of extra bits that were not what solved Your issue.